# Storing multiple types and returning single type on request

Tags: c++, templates, types, type-conversion

I need to create a class that stores multiple User defined types. It should return one of them, on demand. Is there a way to implement one function to return all the types?

Please note: I cannot use Boost libraries. I need to implement in Visual Studio

```
class One {};
class Two {};
class Three {};

enum Type
{
  OneType,
  TwoType,
  ThreeType
};
class GenericType
{
  template <typename T>  // --- How to implement this function
  T getValue(Type type)
  {
     switch(type)
     {
       case One: return oneType;  // Error
       case Two: return twoType;
       case Three: return threeType;
     }
  }
  shared_ptr<OneType> oneType;
  shared_ptr<TwoType> twoType;
  shared_ptr<ThreeType> threeType; 
  Type m_type;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you have an [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) class that does the job. You can retrieve needed element with `std::get`, like this:

```
// Create a tuple
std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<OneType>, std::shared_ptr<TwoType>> tuple{null, null};
// Get element
std::get<std::shared_ptr<OneType>>(tuple)
```

Comment: std::get() can only fetch the item of an index (provided as an argument)

Answer (score 1):

This declaration,

```
template <typename T>  // --- How to implement this function
T getValue(Type type)
```

… where `Type` is an `enum`, makes the run time choice of argument determine the compile time choice of function result type, or alternatively requires the run time selection of argument value to be compatible with the compile time choice of type.

The former is backward in time, so it's not on, and the latter is just silly.

If an ordinary function template is OK for you, then the solution is simple: specialize it for each relevant type.

If you need to have run time selection, then instead use a common result wrapper type. For value semantics it can be a class with `union` members, i.e. a *discriminated union*. For reference semantics it can be a pointer to a common base class of the possible result types.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't quite get it. What do you mean by common result wrapper type. Do you mean std::tuple?

Comment: @Neo: That would be something like `boost::variant`. Since you cannot use Boost you'd have to do it yourself. Hence the implementation suggestions. `std::tuple` isn't a solution to anything, since it just exposes the members: there is no problem to be solved if you can just expose the members and that's enough for the client code.